# Reading Xml using jQuery $(this).text() in IE

Tags: jquery

I have tried to fetch data from XML. I need to get children (parm) data from the parent tag (regstudio).

```
$(xml).find("regstudio").each(function() { 
    $( $(this).text() ).find("parm").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Here `$(this).text()` is not working in IE.

Here the XML I have used:

```
<regstudio> 
<![CDATA[ 
 <config> 
   <control id="0"> 
    <parm name="PropPage">propRegPage</parm> 
    <parm name="PropTitle">Page</parm> 
    <parm name="RequiredMark">*</parm> 
    <parm name="ShowIfReged">F</parm> 
    <parm name="ShowIfNoReq">F</parm> 
   </control> 
  </config>  
]]> 
</regstudio>
```

Comment: <regstudio>
<![CDATA[
<config>
<control id="0">
<parm name="PropPage">propRegPage</parm>
<parm name="PropTitle">Page</parm>
<parm name="RequiredMark">*</parm>
<parm name="ShowIfReged">F</parm>
<parm name="ShowIfNoReq">F</parm>
</control>
</config>
]]>
</regstudio> This is XML from which am trying to get values

Comment: Dont throw it into comments, format it properly in the question

Comment: Formatted - as in so that it's readable. You're new here, so ive done you some favours. You'll get better answers quicker if you spend a bit of time making your question readable, and with plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you need to use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) to parse xml and then wrap that in a jQuery object using `$(...)`.

So what you want is:

```
$($.parseXML(xml)).find("regstudio").each(function() { 
   ....
}
```

This appears to work in all browsers according to my quick test: http://jsfiddle.net/U99Qg/